# Providing 5V from 12V battery with minimal energy loss

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

I notice that in switching power supplies for computers the final stage, where they convert, say 16V to 5V, often just a resistor is used to draw down the voltage. So, they are dumping 12V, which I guess means they are wasting (sending to ground or turning into heat) more than twice as much energy than they are delivering to the load. Ideally, I would like to avoid using resistors entirely.

If I have a 12V DC source like a battery and I want to *efficiently* supply 5V, is the logical way to do it using capacitors? For example in a configuration like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX3V53m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will the caps bleed off heat the way a resistor will? If so, how can I estimate the loss per unit time?

Comment: What is the effect of a capacitor in a DC circuit?

Comment: Where did you see this design that uses a resistor to drop 16 V to 5 V?

Comment: Related old question: [how to reduce DC voltage using resistors?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75448/)

Comment: @ThePhoton I specifically said I do not want to use resistors, so how is that question related (other than as an example of what I do not want to do)?

Comment: Because the answers tell you what the alternatives are.

Comment: Another related question: [What is the advantage of a switching over a linear power supply?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/135029/)

Comment: Wait aren't capacitors only used in this way if the voltage supply is AC? I'm genuinely confused.

Comment: @Bradman No, it is the OP who is confused.

Comment: @EJP well the OP confused me.

Answer (score 5):

> If I have a 12V DC source like a battery and I want to efficiently supply 5V, is the logical way to do it using capacitors?

No. The capacitor symbol gives a clue. The two parallel lines represent the plates of the capacitor. The gap between them represents the insulation between them. No direct current can flow.

It is possible to get AC to flow through the capacitor as the plates accept current charging and discharging on each alternation of the applied voltage. Its impedance (AC resistance) in this case can be calculated from \$ Z = \frac {1}{2 \pi f C} \$ where *f* is the frequency.

> I notice that in switching power supplies for computers the final stage, where they convert, say 16V to 5V, often just a resistor is used to draw down the voltage.

Switching regulators use inductors and transformers to change voltage. The only time resistors would be used is for the feedback circuit. These would be high value resistors forming a potential divider and the current through them should be negligible in the efficiency calculations.

Comment: Yes, I have. Can you include an example in your question?

Comment: @TylerDurden as transistor said, can you provide an example schematic where the situation you mention occur? Are you sure you don't mistake some sort of bleeding resistor put across the rails as a way to generate the lower voltage?

Comment: @TylerDurden 100 ohms by itself won't do that. There would also have to be exactly 45R shunt resistance, including whatever the 5V load is drawing. These values are far too small, and the wasted power far too high, to be plausible. You must have misunderstood, just as you have totally misunderstood capacitance in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, the capacitor will not dissipate any power. However, a real capacitor will have an equivalent series resistance (ESR) which represents the loss you should see when current is flowing.

Now, a capacitor at startup is uncharged and since it behaves as a short at that time, the initial current drawn from your source is going to be large.

Another thing is that if you were to connect a load to this capacitive voltage divider, at some point, your load will discharge \$C_2\$ (in the circuit below) and because \$C_1\$ won't allow any more current to flow past itself after getting charged up to the value of \$V_{DC}\$, then the voltage at the load will be zero.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD62B2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The following are simulation results:
[image]

The green plot is the output voltage decaying from an initial value (the value \$C_2\$ gets charged up to) to zero.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, so how can I get a 5V supply from a 12V battery with a minimum of energy loss.

Comment: @TylerDurden I would use a dc-dc converter (step-down), they are very efficient and cheap

Comment: @Tyler Durden: Answer: By following the links and reading the linked questions and answers provided in the comments to your question

Answer (score 0):

This is like Sixto Cabrera's answer but with a different set of components and plots.

[image]