# 230vac / 5vdc power supply design

Tags: power-supply, power, diodes, ac, dc

I am making my own basic bench power supply mainly for testing logic gate circuits, relays, flip flops etc, that I can move around to different locations.

The circuit of the entire schematic will be on a PCB inside a plastic enclosure. It is a 230Vac to 5Vdc regulated power supply. Below is my circuit design:

[image]

For the 5Vdc regulator I am using the L78S05CV voltage regulator IC.

1. Do I need to provide any other additional short circuit/overcurrent protection? According to the datasheet short circuit protection is built in to the IC (see below for sheet)
2. Any other issues/improvements with this circuit please feel free to say?

[image]

Comment: That's rather a lot of work to get something that does the same job as a USB phone charger - 5 V, 2 A. Had you considered that?

Comment: Buy a cell phone fast charger - more safe, compact and can actually reach 2 A. If you insist on making your own, at least make an adjustable voltage PSU - see the datasheet.

Comment: C1 is going to have to be a lot larger value.

Comment: Before you go further, calculate the power your regulator chip will dissipate, and check the thermal resistance specs in the datasheet. Now start shopping for a heat sink that can bring down the thermal resistance by a factor of 5 or 10.

Comment: Yeah I know it would make more sense to buy a USB charger, I'm more interested in learning about simple power supply designs, than actually making it, but it would come in useful. Also out of curiosity, are any USB phone chargers (not powered from PC) mains earth referenced?

Comment: @ThePhoton Woah, actually that's a big problem. IC power loss = (17Vin - 5Vout) / 1amp = 12W! How can this power loss be reduced other than decreasing the input voltage?

Comment: @Unimportant Yeah, that's a mistake in the schematic. Should be more like     (1amp * 50Hz) / 1v ripple = 20,000uF cap. This is a pretty big cap.

Comment: No need for the bulk filter cap to be so large.  The minimum dropout voltage of the regulator is 2 V.  With 15 V peak across the cap, that's 10 V of headroom so you don't need to keep the ripple at 1 V.  3300 uF should do.

Comment: [What is the advantage of a switching over a linear power supply?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/135029/6334)

Comment: Also, the larger the ripple, the lower the heat dissipation in the regulator.

Comment: @AnalogKid Thanks for your answer. Is this because the average input voltage to the regulator is reduced?

Comment: @David777 Do I gather you don't actually intend on building a basic topology power supply, but instead just want to understand how you might go about doing a design should you want to?

Comment: @jonk Well I was going to build this circuit as I need a power supply, but the schematic will need some more work. But yes, I am interested in learning how to design power supplies also.

Comment: @David777 Designing a power supply like the one you talk about (except NO USE OF ICs!) is what I look back upon as one of the more important steps I took, when much younger. It's a good project as it is easier to understand and grapple with, yet has enough interesting things to learn. This means you aren't biting off more than you can chew and you will succeed if you put in a little effort. Yet it also teaches you some of the problems and why more complicated designs are often chosen, too. It's a great learning experience.

Comment: @jonk Yes I agree, by designing, building and testing circuits is the only way to learn. If I didn’t post this question in this forum I would have not received this knowledge from smart people pointing out my design limitations/flaws and how you should be thinking when designing such a circuit

Comment: @David777 One of the problems I faced, while learning to do it, was that I wanted a power supply in order to learn about transistors enough so that I could design a power supply. Kind of a *chicken and egg problem*, so to speak. I also wanted a voltmeter. I grew up too poor at the time to be able to afford either a good power supply or even a voltmeter (dad dead when very young, as a child I worked the fields picking vegetables just to survive and lived in a house without walls.) So it was a very difficult problem. I got parts by asking companies when I could. And succeeded. But hard won.

Comment: @David777  threres room for 5V ripple before the regulator, and hang-time is not a full half-cycle, only from the crest until it rises bast 9V  1600uF is probably enough.

Comment: for one volt ripple at one amp, use C = 1 / 120 Hz, or 8300uf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Literally any diode can respond to a 50Hz wave. But try a full bridge rectifier that can handle >1.5A, eg from [here](https://export.farnell.com/c/semiconductors-discretes/diodes/bridge-rectifier-diodes?searchref=searchlookahead).
2. You could, for protecting the circuits under test. But that demands other components and schematic. See the datasheet of the regulator and do a quick search on short-circuit protection, to see what fits you.
3. Some suggestions:

   - Bigger caps at the input and output of the regulator. Use electrolytic and MKT/MKP in parallel in order for the PSU to be able to respond both at low and high frequencies.
   - At DC side, use a fuse >1A.
   - Search for a heatsink that is suitable. As you have already noticed, you have quite a lot losses. Input voltage of the regulator is \$V_{IN} = \sqrt{2} \cdot12= 17V\$. Maybe find a transformer with less output voltage?

Have you considered buy a phone charger for now and design a SMPS? you will gain much more knowledge and experience.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Yeah, I will get something temporary.

Comment: You forgot the voltage drops in the bridge rectifiier. The rectified peak voltage would be 17 - 2 * 0.7 = 15.6V

Comment: @Pzy That's right! my apologies. But still 15-5 = 10 V are still quite many volts. A transformer with \$7 \tilde{V_{SEC}} = 9.87 V_{SEC,peak} \Rightarrow 9.87-1.4 = 8.5V\$ would be a must more suitable choice.

Answer (score 1):

Learning is one thing but building this circuit based upon something that would have made sense forty years ago just does not come across as smart. You will pay more just for the heatsink that will be needed to cool the 7805 in this design than you would for a typical 5V USB charging type device.

As a matter of fact the current trend of cycling through new smart phones every couple of years means that there are a plethora of smart phone chargers laying around everywhere. For example a quick trip to a donation outlet store such as Goodwill will typically turn out a shelf full of chargers that can be had for a buck or two!

These chargers are also based upon switching technology so can provide you a whole 5V 2A output with very little heat in the converter.

Comment: I think you are correct, I won't waste the money building this circuit. I forgot about the power loss in the 7805 IC.

Comment: I agree that today it's better to get some cheap tools that others have designed and learn whatever you are motivated to learn with the use of those good tools. The times are different and sophisticated devices are nearly free, as you point out. However. That doesn't change the fact that as far as learning experiences go, starting by taking on a project that involves complex control theory, for example, isn't a good first step, either. So get the good tools, then go back and struggling with simple projects remains a good approach. Even if those simple projects can't compete anymore.

Comment: Even beyond the simple 5V SMPS adapter, there are 'universal' power supplies like this: https://www.amazon.com/Powseed-Universal-Adapter-Household-Electronics/dp/B01MT5WVCG  These are very flexible for use from 5-15V, with one important caveat """Always change the voltage with the unit turned off""". The use of break before make switches means that the output may rise between switch positions.